# Returning a value in OUTPUT parameter in a sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns all fields of an object.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer
(
   @CustomerId int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @CustomerId=CustomerId,FirstName,LastName FROM Customers
END
```

I want to be able to return the id of the object as an output parameter, so that another sproc can use it. I get this error in this example:

```
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with 
data-retrieval operations.

CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer_and_more
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CustomerId int

EXEC getCustomer @CustomerId OUTPUT

-- call another sproc that requires this @CustomerId
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your `SELECT` statement assigns variable values, all fields in the SELECT must assign to a local variable.

Change your SPROC to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer
(
 @CustomerId int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @CustomerId=CustomerId, @FirstName = FirstName, @LastName =LastName 
    FROM Customers
```

You don't have to use them variables, but they must be assigned in this fashion.

Your **BETTER** option is to remove the fields. If they're not needed, don't bother selecting them.

**[EDIT] to respond to your comment**

So, you could do what you're looking to do by splitting out the assignment of the variable and selecting the other fields as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer
(
 @CustomerId int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @CustomerId=CustomerId FROM Customers

    SELECT FirstName, LastName, {A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_FIELDS}
    FROM
        Customers
```

This would allow you to get your output param and select all of the other data without having to define params for each field. You have to weigh ease of use (not having to define a lot of local vars) versus performance (having to run two statements as opposed to one). This seems a little strange to me however.

I wasn't quite clear if you needed the other values from the GetCustomer sproc available to you in getCustomer_and_more. If you do, then yes, you'd have to define OUTPUT params for each value you needed

Comment: I need all the fields, of which there are many, because i need to construct an object in the business layer. So you are saying that declaring variable for each field is the only way to do this?

Comment: I have a possible solution for you but SO is bugging out when I try to edit the post. As soon as I can respond, I'll post in my main response.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in the query: `FirstName` and `LastName` are redundant.

```
SELECT @CustomerId = CustomerId
FROM Customers
```

Also I assume you have more than one customer in the Customers table. So this query will return the last CustomerId, which I assume is not what you want. So you need to add `WHERE` condition, or `TOP 1`.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer  (@CustomerId int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    select @CustomerId = id
    from Customer
    where <SomeCondition>
END
```

**[EDIT]** As you state that there the error is not in the `SELECT` statement and it compiles and works fine, here is the proof. Please try this code will work without problems.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer
(
   @CustomerId int OUTPUT,
   @CustomerName varchar(10) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @CustomerId = 666, @CustomerName = 'Test'
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomer_and_more
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CustomerId int
    DECLARE @CustomerName varchar(10)

    EXEC getCustomer @CustomerId OUTPUT, @CustomerName OUTPUT

    SELECT @CustomerId, @CustomerName
END
GO

EXEC getCustomer_and_more
```

This is the code that is causing your error:

```
DECLARE @CustomerId int

SELECT @CustomerId = CustomerId, FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers
```

This is not legit `SELECT` statement. Try this code and you will see exactly the same error as you showed in the question.

Comment: There is no error in the query and I need all the fields to construct the object in the business layer. Also, I need to call this sproc from another sproc and use just CustomerId in it. There is a `WHERE` clause that guarantees that 0 or 1 record is returned. This does not answer my original question.

Comment: @kateroh The error that you are seeing is because of the `SELECT` in your first proc. The second proc is correct. The problem that you are having is not related to output parameter per se.

Comment: @kateroh - added a query to my answer that demonstrates your error.

Comment: "So this query will return the last CustomerId" - unwarranted assumption - if there are multiple rows in the table, it will return *a* CustomerId, but which one is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - well, I will try to clarify: it will return CustomerId from the last row. And yes, without `ORDER BY` it is not known what the last row will be.

Comment: @Alex ok, there is an error in my query, but this still does not answer my question

Comment: @kateroh - what is your question? I saw this `I want to be able to return the id of the object as an output parameter, so that another sproc can use it`. I thought I showed in my answer how to pass OUTPUT parameter to another proc, didn't I?

Comment: @Alex You showed how to do this by selecting only 1 field in the `SELECT` statement, which is not an option. Thanks anyway

Comment: @kateroh -  you didn't mention in the question that you need to return multiple parameters. You said that you want to return `id of the object`. I updated the answer to show how to return multiple parameters.